# Gratis SNMP decoder

Tags: gratis, protocol, snmp

Python open source would would be best, followed by C++ or C, followed by an online site, followed by a Windows app.

Input is a byte stream, output is human readable code.

Comment: Can you explain what do you meany by "decoding"?

Comment: What is your desired output? Do you want to parse SNMP network packets into human-readable text information, like Wireshark does? Or do you want the output to compile information from possibly several different SNMP network packets?

Comment: Human readable, Nicholas. I have coded most of it, but am still willing to drop it and use someone else's